# Can two bitcoin chains co-exist if one copied the code and ran a parallel chain?

Tags: altcoin

If someone forked the code without changing any of the fundamental properties and connected nodes / miners, could they not disrupt the main (original chain)?

Comment: What exactly *would* they change?  What do you mean by "disrupt"?

Comment: I agree with Nate, you'll need to be more specific what remains the same and what changes to be able to get a good answer. For example, do you count the "Genesis Block" among the fundamental properties? Does the forked version use different ports, network magic, etc.?

Comment: if the forked nodes are able to communicate with original nodes (for block propagation), and the rules are all the same, then you would be on the same chain.

Comment: So what I mean is this, Bitcoin in its current form running chain A, then someone comes along and runs a new version but from the genesis block again, so from 0 TX onwards without previous history. Would this not upset the current chain if the nodes connected to the same network or would the existing nodes simply reject it ?

Comment: Full nodes would simply follow the best chain, which means that they would ignore this new chain and end up on the existing chain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is currently happening.  There are many different implementations of the Bitcoin protocol.  You can see [here](https://coin.dance/nodes/share) the a graph of how many people are currently using different implementations.

Comment: running a different implementation does not necessarily mean that you have a different chain.

Comment: thanks this is helpful. I am researching for an article and just want to cover my bases. kudos.